# Object orientation - iOS isEqual method in superclass, will it work correctly for subclasses?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, inheritance

I have two `isEqual` method that looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)isEqualToObject:(IdentifiableObject *)object {
    if ([self identifier] == [object identifier])
        return YES;
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)otherObject {
    if (otherObject == self)
       return YES;
    else if (!otherObject || ![otherObject isKindOfClass:[self class]])
       return NO;
    return [self isEqualToObject:otherObject];
}
```

This is placed in a generic superclass that other classes inherit from.

Will this work as expected (or as I want)? Or should the `isEqual` methods be placed inside each subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your subclasses will inherit this method, it works as expected. In your `isEqual:` method you  make use of `self`, so you're referring to current class instance.

Here an example:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* myName;

@end

// -------

@implementation ClassA

- (BOOL)isEqualToObject:(ClassA *)object {
    if (self.myName == object.myName)
        return YES;
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)otherObject {
    if (otherObject == self)
        return YES;       // instead of "![otherObject isKindOfClass:[self class]]"
    else if (!otherObject || !([otherObject class] == [self class]))
        return NO;
    return [self isEqualToObject:otherObject];
}

@end
```

sample usage

```
ClassA* a1 = [[ClassA alloc]init];
ClassA* a2 = [[ClassA alloc]init];
a1.myName  = @"joe";
a2.myName  = @"joe";

ClassB* b1 = [[ClassB alloc]init];
ClassB* b2 = [[ClassB alloc]init];
b1.myName  = @"frank";
b2.myName  = @"frank";

ClassC* c1 = [[ClassC alloc]init];
ClassC* c2 = [[ClassC alloc]init];
c1.myName  = @"donnie";
c2.myName  = @"donnie";

NSLog(@" a1 == a2 -> %hhd",[a1 isEqual:a2]); // Match
NSLog(@" b1 == b2 -> %hhd",[b1 isEqual:b2]); // Match
NSLog(@" c1 == c2 -> %hhd",[c1 isEqual:c2]); // Match

NSLog(@" a1 == b1 -> %hhd",[a1 isEqual:b1]); // Doesn't match
NSLog(@" b1 == c1 -> %hhd",[b1 isEqual:c1]); // Doesn't match
NSLog(@" c1 == a1 -> %hhd",[c1 isEqual:a1]); // Doesn't match
```

Comment: What implications for `hash` and subclasses with additional properties?

Comment: You're right. As Apple says "if two objects are equal, they must have the same hash value". So you should also override the hash method to ensure it matches when isEqual matches, based on his properties. If a subclass required additional properties, it should override hash method again. All depends from which use you will make  for isEqual method

Answer (score 1):

It will work within bounds...

If you implement `isEqual:` you should also implement `hash` so that the equality requirements are maintained. If you don't, and you place your custom object into a collection you may get some unexpected results.

Your custom implementation also doesn't consider subclass custom properties unless they override the superclass implementation. Whether this is an issue depends on how you define equality.

In a lot of cases it's better to not override `isEqual:` but instead to add your own custom comparison method - but, it depends how you want the equality to be used.

Basically, be careful what you override and ensure that you satisfy all of the corresponding equality requirements.